# NSData contentsOfURL constructor returns nil

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm trying to access an API I made in PHP. It works fine in browser, but I can't get this code to fetch any sort of data from any given webpage.

```
var jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com"))
let string1 = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(string1)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update: Here's the output after changing encoding.

[image]

Also, NSURLConnection doesn't start when I do that either. Might be a related issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code is correct but the data isn't in UTF it seems so it fails to make the NSString.

fails in swift & objC

for that server data is in `NSISOLatin2StringEncoding`

it differs based on the HTTP endpoint and normally UTF8 is fine

---

```
    var jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com"))
    let string1 = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
    println(string1)
```

shows the page's sourcecode

Comment: The error is gone, but it prints a blank line with all URLs I try.

Comment: I just copied that code and pasted it. I don't have any output but a blank line. I added the screenshot of the console box. Maybe an Xcode problem? Even though its a fresh install.

Comment: ah it is ISOLatin for me -- encoding may differ again for you - based on your region -> google does a lot of forwarding.

Comment: use an api you control / of which you know the encoding ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to use one that I made, a straight up PHP page that `echo`s ASCII-compliant characters. I also tried other people's.

Comment: NSURLConnection won't work either. Could be a related problem.

Comment: Yeah lol, it's on the same computer as this. Maybe I should reboot or something.

Comment: Unreal, restarting Xcode made it start to work. Might be a bug in Xcode 6? Haha, thanks for your help. Back to coding!

Comment: yes, xcode6 does have a few rough edges here and there :) glad it works