# Upgraded to Xcode 6.1.1, now NSData(contentsOfURL:) always returns nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have made no changes to my project, only known change was upgrading from Xcode 6.1 to Xcode 6.1.1 via the Mac App store.

The following line is returning nil regardless of the URL provided. This is in Swift.

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://cnn.com")!)
```

I've disabled Little Snitch, ie outbound firewall to no effect. I can't imagine what else could be causing this other than the change to Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

I have previously had Xcode 6.1.1 beta installed, but had backed down to 6.1 due to a crashing issue.

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25950823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rebooting` the `Mac` fixed it. I hadn't `rebooted`since updating to `Xcode 6.1.1`.

Comment: Remember the time when Mac users laughed at Windows people because they always had to reboot to make their computers work? :-)