# NSData(contentsOfURL: url) always returning nil

Tags: swift, null, nsdata, nsurl

I have this code in a new playground

```
import Foundation

let blogsURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Francis/Documents/Xcode_projects/KM registratie/blogs.json")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: blogsURL)
```

On the second line the playground tells me that it (correctly) initialised the URL referring to `file:///Users/Francis/Documents/Xcode_projects/KM%20registratie/blogs.json`
and on the third line the playground tells me that data is `nil`

I already googled around but no question seems to be the exact same problem. I found this "[NSData contentsOfURL constructor returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944730/nsdata-contentsofurl-constructor-returns-nil)", but neither restarting Xcode nor restarting my entire computer fixes the problem.

Comment: Not sure about the %20, but it should probably be an escaped space instead of encoded : `"/Users/Francis/Documents/Xcode_projects/KM\ registratie/blogs.json"`

Comment: you only escape when you don't put parentheses around a path right? In that case there's no need to escape the space. But I tried it anyway, it gives a syntax error on the back slash

Comment: I guess, the playground is in its own sandbox and cannot access files outside.

Comment: maybe need 2 slashes so you aren't escaping in the `String` but you are in the path creation, though it may be that %20 is appropriate

Comment: I already answered the question, thanks to @vadian, but I do wonder now if %20 is appropriate in a system path :p

Comment: @Fr4nc3sc0NL any space character in an URL has to be percent escaped even in a file system URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playgrounds are sandboxed and it seems that there isn't an easy way to reach outside their "box". [XML parsing in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722937/xml-parsing-in-swift/26723557#26723557) the title of this question is a bit misleading, the answer on it does answer this question

Answer (score 0):

It's answered here:

[XML parsing in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722937/xml-parsing-in-swift/26723557#26723557)

The problem is that your URL isn't pointing where you think it is. You're trying to open a URL in a subdirectory in your sandbox, and it doesn't exist.

You'll need to open the package contents of your playground (right click on the playground and select "Show Package Contents", add a folder called "Resources", and copy your file directly there.

Then you can get the file from the main bundle:

```
let url: NSURL! = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("blogs", withExtension: "json")
```